# Is there a way to import sass abstracts into all the vue components - While using vite as a build tool

Tags: vue.js, sass, vite

I'm working on a project which uses `vue3`, `vue-router`, `vuex` and `sass` with `vite` as the build tool.

> In the past, while working with vue-cli, I used to have a
> `vue.config.js` file which imports the sass abstracts to all the components for me. It uses the
> webpack `sass-loader` to prepend the sass abstracts to each and
> every component.

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `
                    @import "@/styles/abstracts";
                `
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to replicate the same kind of behavior, but this time using vite as the build tool. The above `vue.config.js` won't work as it requires webpack and the fact that vite doesn't support webpack. The docs also doesn't seem to help me in this case.

So Is there a way to import **sass abstracts** into all the components without manually importing them in each and every component ?

I'm referring to all the sass variables, sass mixins and sass functions collectively as sass abstracts.

Comment: No answers to this yet? I have the same question.

Answer (score 4):

Vite has [css.preprocessorOptions](https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-preprocessoroptions).

I have:

```
// vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
              @import "@/styles/mixins.scss";
              @import "@/styles/variables.scss";
            `,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Note: I have resolved the path `@/` to alias my `src` folder which means that when it's referenced in any `.vue` file, it will be refer to the same file. If you use a relative path here, I do not think it will point at the correct `.scss` files unless it's at the same level as your `vite.config.ts`.